# Generate a normal distribution graph using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, graph

I need to generate a Gaussian graph (bell curve) using a given average and standard deviation. How can this be completed in C#?
If it can be completed in Classic ASP - even better :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would manually generate the values using the forumulas from [this page](http://www.tushar-mehta.com/excel/charts/normal_distribution/index.htm) then use [Google Charts](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/) to render it on the client.  This would work in C# or classic ASP.

Comment: This is a great idea - it seems that this could solve it.
Though the formulas from that page are in Excel, not C# or ASP (VBScript). If you know of any formulas in ASP for this, it could really help.
Thanks

Comment: Here's the math formula that Excel's NORMDIST function uses: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb239430.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Do you absolutely need to generate an image on the fly with ASP? If not you might be looking at the Silverlight/Flash charts that already exists such as  http://www.fusioncharts.com/ or http://www.amcharts.com/ ?

Comment: I tried to look in this chart solutions - but none can get an AVG and StdDEV and generate a graph.
I'll need to generate normal distribution points and then send them to the graph.
I hoped it could be made simpler.